# How an I extract the JSON data from my Google Custom Search API AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-api, google-custom-search

I'll try and keep it simple and quick.

I am using Google's custom search api to search my website. I use a very basic AJAX call to post a search query.

```
       var search_term = 'mysite.com'; 
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var response = this.responseText;
          console.log(response);
        };
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", search_term, true);
      xhttp.send();
```

It works as expected. I `console.log` the `this.responseText`. The syntax returns something like the below(I shortened it ALOT to make the question easier to read).

```
// API callback
hndlr({
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json"
},
"queries": {
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - site:www.mysite.com.au gallery",
    "totalResults": "150",
    "searchTerms": "site:www.mysite.com.au gallery",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "006655164624831528:nz6utbz01b0"
   }
  ]
}
});
```

The syntax looks like a function, I would like to extract the inner JSON object and use that data. I have tried to Google this, but no luck, probably because I don't know what to search for exactly.
How can I do this?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks All,

Moe

Comment: If your response is coming back in that format then it's already parsed. Just access it. `this.responseText.queries.request[0].title`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @trevster34. That worked. 
I also included a hndlr() function and was able to access the data using response.items notation. cheers

Comment: Of course. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

we can also use jquery for this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

            var data = GetURLParameter('search_data'); //that data we passed for google search

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=your key&cx=YOUR CX&q='+data, function(resp)
            {

                 var i=0;

                 while(i<=10)
                {
                    var title=resp.items[i].title;
                    var link=resp.items[i].link;


                    alert(title);

                    i++;
                }

            });
});

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```